# Dozer Mapper Performance

Tags: java, hadoop, thrift, dozer

I've been doing some work within my hadoop job and was able to quickly get Dozer mapping between object hierarchies.   I have some complex objects that I need to convert to Thrift types.   When I enable this mapping, it adds nearly 5 minutes of execution to my 5 minute processing run (making it 10 minutes) plus or minus some variation.  I am printing out the Dozer statistics, and it is clearly showing that it is spending 5 minutes doing mappings.   Is there any way to speed this up?  Is there any advantage to defining the mapping vs letting it auto-map via reflection?

This is how I am printing out the stats:

```
GlobalStatistics stats = GlobalStatistics.getInstance();
for (Statistic stat : stats.getStatsMgr().getStatistics()) {
    for (StatisticEntry entry : stat.getEntries()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
SUPER_TYPE_CHECK: 970293
SUPER TYPE CHECK: 6
MAPPER_INSTANCES_COUNT: 1
MAPPING_SUCCESS_COUNT: 10093
FIELD_MAPPING_SUCCESS_COUNT: 25883488
MAPPING_TIME: 478486
```

One thing I'm curious about is that the generated Thrift classes have public fields as well as getter/setter methods.  I need to go back and regnerate them in the Bean style with private fields.  Would Dozer be doing extra work on these public fields?  How can I speed up this mapping? I know there are tradeoffs of development time vs execution time and I can always drop down to implementing my own conversion, but I am surprised at how large the performance penalty is for using Dozer.  Am I doing something wrong?

Also, why don't I see any statistic data about the dozer cache hit rates?  This page indicates there should be more statistics available: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/configuration/statistics.html

Comment: There is a promising tool for beans mapping: http://mapstruct.org/